# Set equality with custom compare function

Tags: c++, stl, set, operators, equality

I am using sets of user-defined types and a custom compare function. When I try to use the `==` operator between sets I get a compile-time error. What am I missing?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <set>

// my user-defined type
struct IntWrapper {
    int value;
};

// my compare function
struct LessComparer {
    bool operator()(const IntWrapper& lhs, const IntWrapper& rhs) const {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<IntWrapper, LessComparer> s;
    assert(s == s);  // I would expect this to work
}
```

[Here you can see the error.](http://ideone.com/2tklTY)

Comment: Where is your `operator==` (and `operator!=`) ?

Comment: The custom comparator is for comparing elements in a set, not for comparing sets

Comment: It is funny, but [this](http://ideone.com/tn1huh) works. Don't know why, may be compiler thinks that `s` is a function.

Comment: @ilotXXI Maybe comparing pointers.

Comment: @Toris but is it needed? `std::set` only requires a less-than comparison, from which it is easy to get an equality check; otherwise, the set could not be constructed at all since it needs an equality in order to check duplicates.

Comment: @Loreto Once I have element comparison I should also get set comparison, right? Two sets are equal iff their elements are equal...

Comment: @ilotXXI Yes, it is interpreted as a function declaration. You can check it by enabling warnings.

Comment: @effeffe () is not less than comparison.

Comment: @Toris That is just because `std::set` expects the less-than comparator as a functor...

Comment: @effeffe sorry, I missed.

Comment: `Once I have element comparison I should also get set comparison, right? Two sets are equal iff their elements are equal... `I don't think so; LessComparer is not enough.  However, You can reuse it with algorithms like `std::set_difference (s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin(), LessComparer());`

Comment: Think about sorting. Case1: (a < b), case2: (a = b). Result of case1 and case2 will be same (a, b). But a and b are not equal in case1.

Comment: Regarding @Revolver_Ocelot comment about equality and equivalence, I think you can use a functions (or functors or ...) as `Compare` for ordering and a different one for determining equivalence, and not necessarily one of these for equality. I mean it is possible to use two different criteria when deciding order and when deciding equivalence, and a third one for deciding equality.

Comment: @Loreto Yeah, as you see in the comments to the answer, I just learnt about the difference between *equality* and *equivalence* in C++, so now I see, `LessThanComparable` gives equivalence but not equality.

Comment: @Loreto Regarding your last comment: yes, I agree that it may be useful to use different relations in different scenarios. But this seems sensible to me only when these relations are implemented as functions *external* to the class. What puzzles me is that a class can implement `operator<` and `operator==` (and others) in such a way that they are *inconsistent*. I would like such consistency to be expected and enforced (as done by other languages). This seems to me more like asking for trouble than a feature, but maybe I am missing a use case.

Comment: As reference, I was impressed with:
[http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/introducing-c-order-relations/240146592]
Order: irreflexive, antisymmetric, transitive.
Equivalence: reflexive, symmetric, transitive.
And [http://stepanovpapers.com/DeSt98.pdf]
Equality: x == y ⇒ ∀ “reasonable” function foo, foo(x)==foo(y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp

> Key must meet the requirements of EqualityComparable in order to use overloads (1-2).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable

> The type T satisfies EqualityComparable if
>   Given  a, b, and c, expressions of type T or const T
>   The following expressions must be valid and have their specified effects:
>   `a == b`

So, you need to define `operator==` for `IntWrapper` type.

Comment: Accepted, but it does not make sense to me. Why is it needed? I am already defining a less-than comparison, it is easy to get an equality from it.

Comment: @effeffe equivalence != equality. Those are different concepts. If you want set equivalence, you can use `not ((a < b) || (b < a))`

Comment: What is the difference between set equivalence and set equality?

Comment: @effeffe sets are quivalent when all their elements are pairwise equivalent and equal if all their elements are pairwise equal. Two objects are equivalent if no one is ordered before other, they are equal if they compare equal, e.g. if points are ordered by distance from (0; 0), then (0; 5) and (3; 4) would be equivalent, but certainly _not_ equal. So sets containing those elements ordered by that relation can be equivalent and not equal.

Comment: I see, thank you. I would expect C++ to enforce consistency among `EqualityComparable` and `LessThanComparable` for those objects having both, though. Not doing this sounds like asking for trouble to me.